# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar una redirección 300?

Tags: php

Mi archivo .htaccess es el siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(index.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Estoy utilizando un servidor Ionos, pero cuando escribo `example.com/panel.php/3.php` aparecería lo mismo que `example.com/panel`, algo que quiero evitar. Además aparece el error 300 de Multiple Choices. ¿Hay alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es que tienes la reescritura para eliminar extensiones .php por lo tanto creo que si hay alguna redireccion a .php causara conflicto...

> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php...RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

Entonces si example.com/panel.php/3.php te dara el error 300 Puedes probar con

> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
> %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$ RewriteRule ^ %1.php [L] RewriteCond
> %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$ RewriteRule
> ^(index.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,QSA]

Con esto tomará una URL con un solo segmento después del slash y se eescribirá directamente a la versión con la extensión .php...